# How to hide menu clicking anywhere on page?

Tags: angularjs

I have this login menu and its show on click but where ever i click its still open. Now i need to implement when user click anywhere on page that i close this menu.Any suggestion?

```
$scope.toggleLoggedIn = function () {
            $scope.loggedInOpened = !$scope.loggedInOpened;
            $scope.languagesOpened = false;
            $scope.loginOpened = false;  
        };


 <div class="fade-show-hide" ng-show="loggedInOpened" ng-cloak>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInPartial.cshtml")
 </div>
```

I tryed this but without success :

```
 angular.element(document).on('click', function () {
        alert("test");
        if ($scope.loggedInOpened == true) {
            $scope.loggedInOpened = false

        }
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery by chance (I only ask since a click to close directive is a bit easier with that)?

Comment: no..i dont use jquery

Comment: why don't think of `ng-click`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that your scopes are not shared where the two functions are executed? Have you tried changing **$scope** to **$rootScope?** I assume you get the **alert("test")** message when a click occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Create a screen filling but transparent div with z-index:1 and make your login menu z-index: 2. Then add a ng-click on this div which calls a function which makes the transparent div hide again and make you login menu collapse.

Comment: What about any other interactive content on the page? The transparent DIV would mask it...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a directive to transparent div.

```
app.directive('myDraggable', function($document) {
return function($scope, $element, $attr) {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function () {

          $scope.loggedInOpened = !$scope.loggedInOpened;
          $scope.$apply();
}, false); 
}
});
```

Here's the sample.when u click on page "hello" is toggled
[link]http://plnkr.co/edit/3iPQeWWz4sD2J7qT7ixy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is event propagation.

Set a custom directive on an element that covers the main page, a main div, form or even body. Inside this directive bind the element to the click event. Inside the new click event function find your login div, either by id or class and set its CSS display to none. This will hide the div if you click anywhere on the page, even inside it.

Now to prevent the login div from closing if the click inside it add a seperate custom directive to it and bind to click. Inside this just call the stop propagation method on the event and it will remain open.